# Multi-Table Inheritance in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent

For writing on a PDF document, the user should be able to create different "modules" that can be reused in several `Documents`. There are normal modules (`Module`) having the attributes `name, posX, posY` and e.g. `TextModule` which has all the attributes `Module` has but adds `text, font, color, size`. This is what you would normally achieve using inheritance.
I found several ways to build single-table inheritance with Eloquent but this would lead to a lot of `NULL` values in the database because all `Module` objects won't have any `text, font, color` or `size`.
Unfortunately, I have not found any multi-table inheritance documentation for Eloquent.

This is what I have so far:

```php
class Module extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'posX', 'posY'
    ];

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document');
    }
}

class TextModule extends Module
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'text', 'font', 'color', 'size'
    ];
}
```

Furthermore, my apporach was to create two migrations (because I need multi-table inheritance) and have every common attribute in the `create_modules_table` migrations, whereas I have added every "special" attribute to the `create_textmodules_table`.

My wish is to call `Module::all()` to retrieve any kind of modules, so `Module` and `TextModule` in this example. For every object contained in the returned collection it should be possible to call `obj->document` to retrieve the corresponding document (and vice versa for `Document::hasMany(Module::class)` relationship).
At the moment I only receive all `Module` objects when calling `Module::all()` without any error message.

Am I on the wrong track with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sss S's link about polymorphic relationships in Laravel I finally figured out how to solve my issue:

**Models**

```php
class Module extends Model {
  public function moduleable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}

class TextModule extends Model {
  public function module() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Module', 'moduleable');
  }
}
```

**Migrations**

```php
Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->float('posX');
  // ... other fields mentioned above
  $table->morphs('moduleable'); // this creates a "moduleable_id" and "moduleable_type" field
  $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('textmodules', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  // ... only the fields that are exclusive for a TextModule (= not in Module, except "id")
});
```

**Factories**

```php
$factory->define(TextModule::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        // ... fill the "exclusive" fields as usual
    ];
});

$factory->define(Module::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  $moduleables = [
    TextModule::class,
    // ... to be extended
  ];

  $moduleableType = $faker->randomElement($moduleables);
  $moduleable = factory($moduleableType)->create();

  return [
    // ... the fields exclusive for Module
    // add the foreign key for the created "moduleable" (TextModule)
    'moduleable_id' => $moduleable->id,
    'moduleable_type' => $moduleableType
    ];
});
```

**Controller**

```php
public function index() {
  $all = \App\Module::whereHasMorph('moduleable', '*')->with('moduleable')->get();
  return response()->json($all);
}
```

The wildcard `*` will show any specific `Module` (e.g. TextModule, ImageModule) that was configured following the steps above. Adding `->with('moduleable')` directly populates the "specific" attributes for every `Module`. Have a look at the section ["Querying Polymorphic Relationships"](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships) in the official Laravel documentation for further information.

**Output**

```
[{
   "id":1,
   "posX":34.47,
   "posY":17.04,
   "moduleable_type":"App\\TextModule",
   "moduleable_id":1,
   "created_at":"2019-12-02 20:08:01",
   "updated_at":"2019-12-02 20:08:01",
   "moduleable":{
      "id":1,
      "font":"Arial",
      "color":"#94d22e",
      "size":12,
      "created_at":"2019-12-02 20:08:00",
      "updated_at":"2019-12-02 20:08:00"
   }
}]
```

Because I haven't managed to find a comprehensive tutorial for this scenario on the internet I decided to publish my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/laundy/laravel-mti-morph-example) for playing around.

Comment: Sorry for the pointless comment but I've just realized that you were looking into polymorphic table relationships :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a separate table for each special case of Module I would suggest a nested set implementation. It is mainly used for nested categories on web pages but can be in theory used for any kind of parent/child relationships. Have a look at the following [Laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) package.

Comment: I've set up an example using `Laravel-nestedset` but it seems like it is only allowing a nested set consisting out of elements of the same class: `Argument 1 passed to App\TextModule::appendToNode() must be an instance of App\TextModule, instance of App\Module given`

Answer (score 2):

you may use this page for further reference: [Laravel User Types and Polymorphic Relationships](http://richardbagshaw.co.uk/laravel-user-types-and-polymorphic-relationships/)

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I wanted. I tried it in a fresh project and still needed some changes compared to your link. Please see my separate reply showing my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind your data being stored as json (so you know what you loose there) I might suggest a different approach. A very basic example, having a `field` text column, might be (untested code):

```php
class Module extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'posX', 'posY', 'field'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'field' => 'object'
    ];

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document');
    }
}

class TextModule extends Module
{
    protected $appends = [
        'text', 'font', 'color', 'size'
    ];

    public function getTextAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->field->text;
    }

    public function setTextAttribute(string $value): void
    {
        $field = $this->field;
        $field->text = $value;
        $this->field = $field;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Clearly, this way, you're trading data integrity for flexibility so I would suggest it only when the first is far less important than the latter. For example I used this pattern before while creating an html email composer. Each time the management asked for a new field type it took me minutes to implement it, all without having to create new database migrations. But, again, that's just because in this specific project I didn't really mind about data integrity.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! Wouldn't it be even simpler to have an "extension table" that stores key-value pairs and that has the Module Id as their foreign key? Do you know what is better from a performance perspective? Joining on the database or using this implicit `json_decode()`?

Comment: Well, very different approaches. Your approach hits the database, mine the web server (json casting). I'm not that expert in code performances to tell the difference but at a first glance I would tell that mine is faster just because it makes much simpler queries to the database.

Comment: One more thing. Have you thought to use composition instead of inheritance? For instance eager loading will cause you trouble using inheritance. I mean...  `$document->hasMany('App\What?')`.